# Problem with caption

Tags: captions, math-operators

I get error for caption with 2^14 x 2^14 (it is ok in sharelatex but has problem in overleaf and journal editor):

```
 \usepackage{lineno,hyperref, graphicx, caption, color, float, makeidx, amsmath}
 .
 .
 . 

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig6.PNG}
 \captionsetup{justification=centering}
 \caption{...         A\footnotemark \\ with dimensions 2^{25} \times 2^{25}.}
  \label{figure6}
  \end{figure}

  \footnotetext{\url{}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need math mode for this. Maybe you should consider reading a tutorial about maths in LaTeX.

Comment: @TeXnician I miss mention amsmath in question but I added this, problem still exist.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the packages you loaded, but with the use. Math mode is used with `$math here$`. You need it for `\times` and `^`. As I said, a beginner's guide would help out here.

Comment: @TeXnician ok, thx. It was ok in sharelatex without $ and I though it is redundant

Comment: @hoom It was *not* OK in ShareLaTeX; it just didn't show you the error, or you didn't notice it.

Comment: @egreg anyway, ShareLaTeX output pdf is ok.

Comment: You can sometimes, by happy coincendence, get reasonable output even when skipping past an error (which is what ShareLaTeX did). If there were more normal text at the end of that caption, the output would not have been OK. Hence, whenever you see a small red box with a number in it next to the compile button, such as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTN7c.png), something is wrong and you need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

As @TeXnician said, you've missed `$` for math expression. 
`\caption` is fragile command in latex, in this case you can put `\protect` before the `\footnotemark`. Your MWE would be like below.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article}

 \usepackage{graphicx, caption, url}

\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig6.PNG}
 \captionsetup{justification=centering}
 \caption{Figure shows comparison of performance for square matrix         A\protect\footnotemark \\ with dimensions $2^{14} \times 2^{14}$.}
  \label{figure6}
  \end{figure}

  \footnotetext{\url{}}
 \end{document}
```